# No tables shown in NetBeans reverse engineering wizard with Hibernate and PostgreSQL

Tags: hibernate

I am developing  a web application which retrieves the employee details from my postgresql database. Using hibernate in netbeans, while performing the hibernate reverse engineering.
No tables shown in NetBeans reverse engineering wizard with Hibernate and PostgreSQL.
Connection is established and I have checked it in hibernate configuration file, and I added postgres jar file to path also.
Then also I am not getting the tables to be appeared in reverse engineering wizard for selection.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the similar issue. Try the below in the order.

1. Windows - Services. Choose the database connection name. Right click and select connect.
   (If above is the reason, in reverse engineering wizard, you will get an alert - unable to connect to database)
2. If driver is fine, connection is fine but still tables are empty. Check the default schema used while creating the connection. It should be **DBO**

This would resolve the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may be too late.  But I was having the exact same problem.  I then looked in the project properties, and under frameworks, Hibernate was not using the correct database driver.  It appears it uses the first one in the list. My config file was correct because I can use the connection factory and obtain a valid connection to perform native SQL with.

I went to my database services and removed the invalid database connection, went back into the project properties and Hibernate is now pointing to the correct driver. This appears to have solved the problem.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you need to try removing the old connection driver jdbc:Postgres and create another one, but this time in the last step choose Select schema: public.,I had selected the option information_shema, that was the reason that I couldn't see the tables, regards